# Data from PHP form wont insert into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, phpstorm

I am fairly new to PHP and I understand that the syntax/methods I use may be deprecated however please don't mind that.

I have a locally run website and I'm trying to get my user login system to work. On my `register.php` I have a form and for some reason it won't insert the data from the from inside my database even though the syntax for the insert statement seems correct to me, and the connection to my database works.

I have made my MySQL database as follows:

[image: MySQL database]

database.php is as follows (some details blurred):

```
class connectDB {
protected $host, $username, $password, $dbName;

public function __construct(){ 
    $this->host = "mysql:host=<blurred>;dbname=<blurred>";
    $this->username = "<blurred>";
    $this->password = "<blurred>";
}

public function getConnectDB(){ 
    try
    {
        $db = new PDO($this->host,$this->username,$this->password);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->beginTransaction();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo "Unable to connect to database";
        exit;
    }
    return $db;
}
```

register.phtml is as follows:

```
<?php require("header.phtml");   ?>

<body class="bg-light">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container p-3">
        <div class="row pt-5">
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 mx-auto pt-5 shadow bg-white">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 mx-auto pb-5">
                        <div class="panel">
                            <br><br><br><br>
                            <p>Please enter your username and password</p>
                        </div>
                        <form id="Login" method="POST">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmPass" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" name="userRegisterButton" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

register.php code is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();
require("register.phtml");
require("assets/database.php");
 $conn = new connectDB();
 $myDatabase = $conn->getConnectDB();


if(isset($_POST['userRegisterButton'])){ //if search button clicked
$sqlQUERY = "SELECT email FROM users"; //retrieves all emails from users table
$data = $myDatabase->query($sqlQUERY)->fetchAll();

// Checking if username entered by user already exists
$found = false;
foreach($data as $row){
    if (htmlentities($_POST['email']) == $row['email']) { //checks if email already exists in db
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!$found){ // if email does not exist then proceed to register
    if (htmlentities($_POST['pass']) == htmlentities($_POST['confirmPass'])){ // and if passwords match
        $username = htmlentities($_POST['username']);
        $password = htmlentities($_POST['pass']);
        $loa = "user";
        $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
        echo $username;
        echo $password;
        echo $loa;
        echo $email;
        $result = "INSERT INTO users(username, password, loa, email) VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."','".$loa."','".$email."')";
       /* $sqlQUERY = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES ('" . $_POST['username'] . "','" . $_POST['pass'] . "')";*/
        echo $result;
        $myDatabase->prepare($result)->execute();

        $msg = "You have successfully registered, please login";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg'); window.location.replace(\"http://localhost:8090/login.php\");</script>";

    } else {
        // If passwords entered don't match
        $msg2 = "Please check your passwords match";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg2'); window.location.replace(\"http://localhost:8090/register.php\");</script>";
    }
} else {
    $msg3 = "Username already exists, please check again";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg3'); window.location.replace(\"http://localhost:8090/register.php\");</script>";
}
```

}

I have echoed out some details to help with debugging, and the `$result` that gets echoed (just after the insert statement) shows me the syntax is correct bar one detail. For some reason the statement it echoes out changes the commas in the statement to fullstops, which of course isn't SQL syntax (P.S. this might just be the way the statement has echoed out). Written example of this is:

Correct syntax i.e. what it should be doing:

```
insert into users (username, password, loa, email) values ('test2', 'admin', 'user', 'test1@gmail.com');
```

VS what comes up on the echo:

```
insert into users (username. password. loa. email) values ('test2'. 'admin'. 'user'. 'test1@gmail.com');
```

One major thing to note is that no errors come up on the PhpStorm console to tell me that the insert statement failed. Also the code after the insert statement runs as intended.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't use prepared statements like this. Values must be passed in a placeholders and bound. That `echo` result` would not occur with this code. `htmlentities` should not be used for storage, only for outputting.

Comment: Putting `$db->beginTransaction()` in your connection code seems like a very bad idea

Comment: `fetchAll` to check if a username already exists is also a terribly inconvenient way to go. Do `SELECT count(*) FROM users where email = ?` if you get a count the user already exists. Also hash your passwords, based on this and previous comment you should look over tutorial.

Comment: @Phil thanks for your comment apologies for that, why do you think it's a bad idea and what would you recommend I do instead?

Comment: @user3783243 What do you recommend I should use to store these values then?

Comment: You should research what a transaction is to start, https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php. With current code/connection you'll need to commit everytime.

Comment: Instead of `htmlentities` you mean? Nothing, store them as they are... or for password, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php Escape/encode for outputting to appropriate platform. `htmlentities` won't help you if you want to view users in HTML browser, should only be used for outputting to an HTML context.

Comment: @user3783243 Yes I plan to use hashed passwords but this was just a simple test for now. Do you have any ideas as to why the code in register.php doesn't insert the values into my database?

Comment: Well the transaction @Phil mentioned would relate to that. Also could be the encapsulation/sql injection issue.

Comment: You're incorrectly using the prepare method from PDO. Please see the PHP manual about that PDO method on PHP site, you cannot use it ignoring how it really works